# GitLab and Docker Compose: Mounted directory is empty inside container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I am trying to use GitLab with Docker-compose to deploy my node app to a Digital Ocean droplet. The problem is that the mounted directory inside the container, which contains the source code of the node application, is empty.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.15.0
# Define working directory and copy source
WORKDIR /app
# copy everything
COPY . .
# npm install
RUN npm install
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    hostname: mongodb
    image: 'mongo:3.4.1'
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
      - MONGODB_USER="mongodbadmin"
      - MONGODB_PASS="mongodbadmin&*&"
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - './data/mongo:/data/db'
    command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null
    restart: always
  server:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - './src:/app/src'
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=dev
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: npm start
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker/compose:latest

stages:
    - publish
    - deploy

variables:
    TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
    TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    tags:
        - deployment
    script:
        - apk update && apk add openssh-client
        - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
        - echo "$ID_RSA" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
        - docker-compose -H "ssh://$SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP" down --remove-orphans
        - docker-compose -H "ssh://$SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP" build
        - docker-compose -H "ssh://$SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP" up
    only:
        - main
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing the volume. That is because the dockerfile itself copies the source code and there is no need for the volume. I only needed the volume in my development environment so that the container gets updated while I make code changes :)

I will create separate docker-compose.yml files: one for development and another for the production environment.